# Display value of a response from an api at JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, api

I'm trying to create a calculator in JavaScript.
In this calculator I have a button to convert the number inputed by user to dollars.
I have an api with a key but somehow I can't make it to display the result on the calculator.

```
case 'convert':
            let eur = parseFloat(num)
            console.log(eur)
            const url = 'https://v6.exchangerate-api.com/v6/my-api-key/pair/EUR/USD/' + eur
            fetch(url)
                .then(response => response.json())
            let converted = JSON.parse(response.json())
            display.value = converted
            num = 0
            break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem you have is that you're not processing the API result properly.

`response` only exists inside your Promise callback. In the initialization of your `converted` variable, `response` is not defined. Following should at least successfully give you the data from the API which you can then use for display. Besides, calling `.json()` on a fetch `Response` already converts the HTTP body to JSON so there is no need to parse it again with `JSON.parse()`.

```js
fetch('https://v6.exchangerate-api.com/v6/my-api-key/pair/EUR/USD/4')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((responseData) => {
        console.log(responseData);
        display.value = responseData;
    });
```

As you haven't provided information on what is behind `display.value`, you may encounter further issues. Also, I hope you have recognized that an API key for this API is required and your URL just says 'my-api-key'.

Comment: I replaced my real api with "my-api-key" just to not shar the real key. display.value it's used to display the result on the calculator.

Answer (score 0):

Method 1:

You can do asyn call your function with await the APIs request

```
let response = await fetch(url);
let converted = JSON.parse(response.json())
display.value = converted
```

Method 2:

Move your parsing code inside the APIs response, and get the converted values and set it to display field